# How can I install Segoe UI font?

Tags: fonts

I want to know the steps to install Segoe UI font on Ubuntu 13.04.

I copied `segoe*.ttf` manually to `/usr/share/fonts` and `/usr/share/fonts/msttcorefonts` and then used `fc-cache -f -v` command, but the font doesn't appear in LibreOffice or in browsers.

What's the correct procedure?

Answer (score 23):

In order to install MS True Type fonts in Ubuntu you have to install the `ttf-mscorefonts-installer` package:

`sudo apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer`

After installing the package regenerate the font cache:

`sudo fc-cache -fv`

Now you can use a bunch of MS True Type fonts in Ubuntu.

`Segoe UI` font, however, is not part of the `ttf-mscorerfonts` package, so you have to search and get a `segoe-ui.ttf` for yourself. (either by extracting it from a windows ISO or installation or by searching through the internet, i guess it should not be too hard to find one...)

When you have our `segoe-ui.ttf` file, copy it in a foldr called `~/.fonts`. If no such folder exists, create it, no problem.

Now again regenerate the font cache: `sudo fc-cache -fv`, and  voilá. Now you are able to use `Segoe  UI` font on ubuntu.

Comment: The link to instal Seoge UI: https://github.com/mrbvrz/segoe-ui-linux

Comment: @Neinstein Thanks! I ran that and then reopened Visual Studio Code, and I can now see `►◄▲▼` correctly. And restarting Brave lets me see them correctly here in the browser too.